Is using human, especially children's bones, a viable alternative to animal based bone char in sugar production?
I understand that this is a morbid subject/question, but please bare with me.
So there is a real world process that cane sugar goes through(not always) to purify/whiten it. Bones of cows(and pigs I believe) are burnt and crushed, then the sugar is ran through it to make white table sugar.
I had a morbid idea for adding to a potential story: instead of animal bones, how about human bones, even the bones of children? Why? IDK, I thought it would make the story darker I guess. This apparently has already been done back in the 1800s after the Battle of Waterloo. They would dig up the bones of fallen soldiers and make bonechar to process sugar with. Not 100% confirmed though, hence my question.
My only issue with this is I heard that the bones need to be dense enough or it will not be suitable for sugar production, and human bones may not be good enough. IDK if this is true and if it is, if it is more so economical rather than an actual production issue.
So my question is are human bones, especially the bones of children, a viable alternative to animal bones in the production of sugar?
Note, when I say viable, I mean bear bones(pun intended ig) viability. So viable as in if it will work to properly process the sugar, not the risks and other issues that come with it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You can use any kind of bone, but they won't all be the same.
When working with char, the density is controlled by how much you grind it. This is because it starts off as a certain level of porus (depending on what you start with), but as you grind it down, it breaks up the fibrous structures and fills in the gaps increasing the density and reducing the surface area.  Being able to reach the ideal density has nothing to do with where you source the char, you just break it down until it hits the required density. So even a very low density bone like chicken or fish bone char can be reduced to the correct density to make a good filter.
That said, density is not the only factor you are looking for.  What you are probably looking for is more fully ossified bones: bones that contain a higher mineral content.  Children have proportionally less "bone" and more cartilage than adults, and the bones that they do have will be less occified than adult bones. This means your bone char will be of a lower quality than that produced from an adult.
So, while child bones will still work, you will need to use a higher volume of bone char to filter a given amount of sugar.  Coupled with the fact that the bones are smaller and less dense to begin with means that it will likely not be an economically competitive source of bone char since even if you have the bones, you will likely need to burn more fuel to char them, construct bigger filtration chambers to accommodate the lower calcium content, and spend more effort grinding them down to the proper density.

Thanks for the extra info.

Human bones would work. There are French accounts of bone char and other products being made from battlefield bones in Napoleonic times or just after.
There is no reason to disbelieve them. Until fairly recently battlefields were a source of everything from fertiliser to false teeth.

plus there is nothing special about human bones, bones are bones. there is no reason to think you could not use human bones.

Putting aside any moral or ethical considerations, the idea seems rather silly: a single cow has much more bone mass than a child or even an adult, or to put it in other terms, to get the same mass of bones you need way less cows than children or adults.
So, unless you have plenty of human bones available, the economy of the process tells you to stay away from your conspecific and look at some bigger animal.

IDK why my comment was removed as I was giving info on my question's purpose(please do tell), but since it was I will give it to you straight: this answer as it is, is offtopic/going against the part of the question saying this is not the info I was looking for. Nothing wrong with addressing the issues solely, but not as an answer. Either it could have been a reply or have at least a sentence that answers my question. I tried to edit in a SINGLE sentence answer just to make your answer work, but nobody(including you) accepted it, So I would kindly like you to edit it yourself or delete this.

Either is fine, but editing it would be better.

@conan from the definition of viable: Capable of success or continuing effectiveness; practicable: synonym: possible. I am answering the question you asked.

"Note, when I say viable, I mean bear bones(pun intended ig) viability. So viable as in if it will work to properly process the sugar, not the risks and other issues that come with it.".
There is no part here that clarifies if it is physically possible to use children's bones bones or not.
